# Dynamics Pattern Javascript

Tags: javascript

I got request on a remote service, this service give me fields with patterns as follows:

```
[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'+-]{1,100}
[0-9a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'+-]{2,10}
```

In square bracket contains allowed symbols.
In curly brackets contains minimal and maximum symbols.

So I have fields and their patterns.

How I can validate entered data by incoming pattern?

Comment: you can use `.match()` function of javascript and pass the pattern within it. since your getting the pattern in regex format itself,you can use that directly within match ().eg:-`str.match(/^[A-Z#@,]+$/)`

Answer (score 1):

Send the string to the `RegExp` constructor and use `test`.

For example:

```
string = "[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'+-]{1,100}"
pattern = new RegExp(string)

alert(pattern.test("This works, привет, 123"));
alert(pattern.test("$☛☛"));
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a78j7/)

Depending on your situation, you might want to add "^" and "$" to the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JavaScript regular expression to solve this.

you can do like this

```
"some test".match(/[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'+-]{1,100}/)
```

which returns ["some"]

or

```
/[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'+-]{1,100}/.test("some test")
```

which returns true

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```
var s = "hello123";

var r1 = "[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'+-]{1,100}"; // the pattern you were given
var reg1 = RegExp("^" + r1 + "$");     // the pattern enclosed in `^` `$`

var r2 = "[0-9a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'+-]{2,10}";
var reg2 = RegExp("^" + r2 + "$");

alert(reg1.test(s)); // false
alert(reg2.test(s)); // true
```

The regular expression has the pattern you mentioned, but enclosed between `^` and `$` - meaning "the whole expression". The first expression fails because there is a number in `s` which is not allowed. The second expression passes - it has only numbers and letters, and between 2 and 10 characters total.